# Inserting data into Excel from PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, export-to-excel, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps app that is fronting a SharePoint data source. My customer has an Excel spreadsheet they use for reporting purposes and would like to be able to export data from the PowerApps interface into their Excel spreadsheet stored on OneDrive. I don't want to push the data to a .CSV file - they already have a formatted Excel workbook with tables, formulas, etc. so I don't want to create extra work for them. Has anyone done this and do you have any examples/videos/etc. on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK- I found a solution. You need two data sources in your app - one to your SharePoint data, and a second to an Excel sheet on OneDrive. On one screen, have a form in View mode that pulls your SharePoint data, and a second in New mode for your Excel sheet. Change the default values on the Excel sheet form to pull from the associated data card values on the SharePoint data source. Add a Submit button that submits the Excel sheet form. This is a very simplified answer but I'd be happy to provide screen shots and examples if anyone is interested.